# How to group SharePoint List records in Microsoft Power Automate?

Tags: group-by, power-automate

We have a SharePoint List with a column **VolunteerManager** - here is a view of the list Grouped By that field:

[image]

The list consists of *Volunteers* and each *VolunteerManager* can have several Volunteers

The fields are:
[image]

We need to send an email to each of the Volunteer Managers with a table of the Volunteers that they are responsible for...

So we need to perform a GROUP BY then loop through and send the email containing the names and contact of the Volunteers...

In SQL this would be simple, in MS Excel this would be done with a PIVOT table...

I looked at [Flow Group By](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Flow-Group-By/ba-p/136820) but had no luck getting this to work in my situation ...

How can I do that in my Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how we did the Group BY in MS Flow, grouping our records by the field **VolunteerManager**

First Get items:
[image]
then a Data Operations SELECT step:
[image]
configured like this:
[image]

then we used an Append to Array Variable step with a UNION expression to return the Aggregated data:
[image]
Next we want to loop through the aggregated/grouped data and inside the loop retrieve all the records for each Volunteer Manager:
First we execute a PARSE JSON step:
[image]

Then we use Set Variable to extract the current Volunteer Name and Volunteer Manager values:
[image]
and use those values for a Get Items step to retrieve the records that have that Volunteer Manager:
[image]

and that's it...after that loop through those records, and we append to an HTML table variable the data for that individual record, Update the item as Processed and move to the next Volunteer Manager ...

I hope this helps